# If printf() is given an incorrect argument type relative to it's respective format specifier, does the C compiler attempt to implicitly convert it?

Tags: c, casting, printf

I read that varying compilers may or may not raise a warning when this is done, but I've not found anything that says explicitly what happens/could go wrong. However, I have observed that my mingw64 g++ compiler at least **seems** to perform a simple implicit conversion (where it can). For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned number = -1;
    printf("%u\n%d\n", number, number);  //%d being incorrect and %u correct
    return 0;
}
```

Simply outputs:

```
4294967295
-1
```

Where the first line is just a wrapped unsigned value (expected), but the second line is clearly not of any unsigned integral type, thus some sort of type conversion has occurred. Is this the whole story? Thanks

Comment: There's no such thing as an "implicit cast" in C. A cast is an explicit conversion. You're asking about an implicit conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `printf` function is variadic, any parameters after the format string are subject to the **default argument promotions**.  This means that any type smaller than `int` is promoted to `int` and `float` is promoted to `double`.  These are the only conversion that happen to the arguments.

If the arguments passed do not match what the format string expects, you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

For example, this is valid:

```
float f = 1.2f;
printf("f=%f\n", f);
```

Because `%f` expects a `double`, and `f` is promoted to a `double` before being passed to the function.

This is not:

```
float f = 1.2f;
printf("f=%d\n", f);
```

Because a `double` was passed but `%d` is expecting to read an `int`.

More examples:

```
short s = 3;
long long x = 5;
printf("%d\n", s);  // valid: s is promoted to int
printf("%d\n", x);  // invalid: no promotion happens and a long long 
                    // was passed but an int was expected
```